# Using Google Drive as a database for a login form

Tags: javascript, php, google-drive-api, text-files

Recently i created a website with Godaddy's website builder . In the website there is a free membership, though here is the problem.

Godaddy's website builder doesn't allow you to create a login area, you have to do that with your own tools, and the other problem is website builder does not allow you to upload any files like html or php or install anything like MySql. It does allow you though to put some code in your website. The current way I'm managing the login function is by putting some JavaScript in my website which i found elsewhere , the bad thing is the usernames and passwords are shown in the source code and every time there is a new user i have to change the code. Not only that, the link of the membership area is also in the source code, currently i change it every month. After doing lots of research and finding nothing i had an idea.

By putting a text file on google drive which contains all usernames and passwords, i could make it act as a database. Then put some code in my website which reads the text file in google drive. If this didn't work (Which i think it does) How about using a spreadsheet? And the code on my website reads the spreadsheet. The link to the membership area (Which is also in my website) Could be in another text file.

I'm new with code, and that is really all i need, the code to make this idea work. If anyone can write the code, please post it below. You have no idea how much this will help. Thanks in advance - Braulio

Comment: Your Godaddy hosting should include a mysql database, no?

Comment: @SuperJer No, It is just the website builder.

Comment: I don't expect that using google drive will be fast, reliable, or secure.  My suggestion would be to go with a full hosting solution with GoDaddy.  If you're not wanting to learn code but still wish to get a website and content up, consider using a pre-built application like Wordpress.  Otherwise, there are loads of tutorials available for learning website development.

Comment: @SuperJer I have reserached but remember that godaddy does not let you upload files, and does not have login features.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes you can use a google spreadsheet. yes it will be 100% secure. look at the spreadsheet api for this.

however, beware of the limitations:

1. there is a limit as to how many cells you can have (in the millions).
2. since all the requests will be made from the same google account, rate limit quotas will apply, and total daily api calls will be limited (to a few million i think).

if you really will have many users, you can workaround these limitations by caching as much as possible the spreadsheet data in your backend.

Comment: look at the spreadsheet api and authentication with oauth2. your question needs to be specific to either of those.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use javascript, you could probably use something like

https://www.firebase.com/

or any other 'database as a service' type thing. This will allow you to query the database, and save to the database with client side javascript.

With firebase you could do something roughly like

```
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com/");

myFirebaseRef.set({
  username: "Braulio",
  password: "pass"

  }
});
```

Just one option